# mbsync - Delete a mail from gmail server but not from the local machine

Tags: imap, mu4e, mbsync

I want to delete mails from gmail server to save my google drive space but I want to preserve them on my local Maildir for a backup. How do I accomplish that. I use mbsync to keep my mails synced and mu4e in emacs as the client.